# In the RichTextBox control DragEnter event fires, but DragDrop event does not fire

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, drag-and-drop, event-handling

I have a test Windows Forms application in VB.NET, which consists of a Form, a RichTextBox, a Label, and a Timer. I need to perform drag-and-drop operations from a Mozilla Firefox browser window into that RichTextBox, namely I need to drag-and-drop text from a web page and web page URLs from the address bar.

Here is the test code of the application:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub RichTextBox1_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.DragEnter
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) Then
            Label1.Text = "Status: DragEnter"
            Timer1.Enabled = True
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub RichTextBox1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.DragDrop
        Label1.Text = "Status: DragDrop"
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Text = "Status:"
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

When I run this application I can drag-and-drop text from a web page, both events fire. But when I try to drag-and-drop web page URLs from the address bar, only the DragEnter event fires, but the DragDrop event does not fire, so the dropping never occurs, despite the DataObject is created and it does contain "DataFormats.Text".

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you live with having the DragAndDrop on the Form? Because this is working for me. With RichtTextBox I could reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi, Alex. Thanks for your help. You've made an interesting observation. Indeed, DragDrop fires on the Form, and it does fire on a TextBox control, but it does not fire on the RichTextBox control. Form's DragDrop event will not do for me, because I need to drop URL's in the RichTextBox, and the Form's event does not fire in that case. This is all strange, because it works in WordPad, and I believe WordPad is built on the same DLL as the RichTextBox control.

Comment: Yet another curious observation: when I drag-and-drop any portion of a URL into the RichTextBox, DragDrop event fires, but when I try it with a complete URL - it does not fire. Something messed up with security permissions?

Comment: I would raise an issue on Microsoft's bug reporting site

Comment: That could be a good idea, if there were a chance that Microsoft would give a damn. Still, it seems making more sense to focus efforts on working this around.